# My SKScene will show sized correctly in the Simulator, before rotation, but not after?

Tags: swift, skscene

**My SKScene will show sized correctly in the Simulator, before rotation, but not after?**

If the Simulator is **preset** to Portrait, my SKScene is sized correctly .. and ditto if **preset** to Landscape.

But, **not** after rotation-in-place.

Here are some code snippets …

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        // thisScene = a String name, e.g. “CreditsScene” or “AboutScene”
        showScene(theScene: thisScene!)

    }   // viewDidAppear


    func showScene(theScene: String) {
                
        view = SKView()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: theScene) {
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }
            
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            
            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true

        }

    }   // showScene


    override func didRotate(from fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        
        if fromInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
            let width =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: thisScene!) {
                print("\(scene)")
                scene.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
                print("\(scene)")
            }
        }
        else {
            let width =  UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: thisScene!) {
                print("\(scene)")
                scene.size = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
                print("\(scene)")
            }
        }
        
        showScene(theScene: thisScene!)
 
    }   // didRotate

}
```

**Here’s the Console output after rotation from Portrait to Landscape:**

name:'(null)' frame:{{-375, -667}, {750, 1334}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}  // **before** Landscape

name:'(null)' frame:{{-590, -410}, {1180, 820}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}  // **after** Landscape

**Then, after rotation back to Portrait:**

name:'(null)' frame:{{-375, -667}, {750, 1334}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}  // **before** Portrait

name:'(null)' frame:{{-410, -590}, {820, 1180}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}  // **after** Portrait

The 2nd lines, “after ..” reverse as they should.

For the life of me, I do **not** understand the 1st lines, “before”?

**and** for both lines what is `name:'(null)'` .. doesn't it have the name `fileNamed:thisScene!`

It’s almost as if

```
if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: theScene) { .. }
```

doesn’t call view.presentScene( .. )

To complete the diagnostics, I have **one** GameViewController and **3** GameScenes (.sks files). I am successful in switching scenes .. but **not** in rotating them **to size**.

Any help is very, very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. See the above code for `showScene`, in particular the 1st line in the `func showScene`:

`view = SKView()`

Eliminate it.

2. Found this jewel here at SO:

The size specified in the .sks file is the size of the scene not the view. Set your scene's scale mode to .resizeFill to force the scene size to always match your view size.

```
scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
```

Comment: Request for opinions = whether I ought to start a *central repository of code* whose purpose is to correctly convert gamepad button presses to (1) switch `SKScenes` **and** (2) rotate `SKScene` -- with and without SKTransitions **and** scaling. It would obviously be lots of work on my part. **But** it would attempt to place all input into one place. It is obvious that I am far far away from being an expert on `Swift`. But, I honestly believe it's long overdue. Anyway, please submit any and all opinions at your convenience.